# What is the best tool to manage test lab computer bookings

Tags: test-management

we have several testlabs, with various computers in different configurations.
Some of these computers belong to a business unit and most of the time are not used. But when these busines units are to do UAT they have priority.

At the moment, we do not have an overview of which computer is used by whom over which period of time.
It would help us a lot to be able to book computers over a period of time.

What would be the best tool to do so (preferably open source) ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: This is really more of a resource management and software recommendation question than a test specific question: you are looking for a software tool to manage the allocation of computers. You may get a better response from http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/